# Using gnuplot with a hidpi screen.

Tags: gnuplot

I am using gnuplot on a hidpi screen (276 dpi). 
The plots I recover are hard to see properly, the lines too thin, the fonts and buttons too small.

Is there any way to configure gnuplot to scale up these parameters for hidpi screens automatically upon start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gnuplot automatically loads an initialisation file on startup, that you can use to change the default linewidths etc. It accepts normal gnuplot syntax. Check `help initialization` to see how it's named and where to place it on your system.

Use e.g. `set terminal wxt lw 2` to change the absolute default linewidth. The sizes given in a later plot command are just multiplicators for the terminal setting. The pointsize and border/tics linewidth are scaled accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me solve the issue. 
In essence it comes down to creating a file called .gnuplot in the home directory with the following code:
   set linetype 1 lc rgb "colour-code" lw 2
   set linetype 2 ...

    set terminal wxt size 1920,1080 enhanced font ",24" persist

Comment: You should rather leave the linetypes as is and just do `set term wxt size ... linewidth 2`. Then you don't have to change the lw of every linetype. The lw in the linetypes are just multiplicators for the absolute width set for the terminal.

Comment: I can recommend to set the fontscale also: `set term wxt ... fontscale 2`